# LINQ Group by SUM

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, group-by

Given the following query

```
Dim Query = From c In DB.Crt _
                        Where c.Member.Locked = False _
                        And c.Member.Verified = True _
                        And c.Ct > 0 _
                        Order By c.Ct Ascending _
                        Select New With {.MemberID = c.MemberID, _
                                         .Ct = c.Ct}
```

how can i group by SUM of the `c.ct`?

something like `SUM OF(c.Ct) > 0`

Comment: You should run Sum method based on some properties, what is related property (seems your ID is unique, so sum on different IDs is meaningless).

Comment: Nice! Now i have two questions!

Comment: First think about what is related property to run sum method, then, edit your current question.

Comment: Are you wanting to group by `MemberID` and sum the `Ct` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim Query =
    From c In DB.Crt _
    Where c.Member.Locked = False _
    And c.Member.Verified = True _
    And c.Ct > 0 _
    Order By c.Ct Ascending _
    Group c.Ct By Key = c.MemberID Into Cts = Group _
    Select New With { .MemberID = Key, .Ct = Cts.Sum() }
```