# Vb.net pare down a lists of objects

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have a list of objects that i need to pare down. The items are variable so I can't really brute force it.

Here is what i'm trying to do...

Original list of objects...

```
"Name":"Apple","Qty":1
"Name":"Banana","Qty":2
"Name":"Apple","Qty":3
"Name":"Banana","Qty":4
"Name":"Strawberry","Qty":5
```

List of objects after paring down...

```
"Name":"Apple","Qty":4
"Name":"Banana","Qty":6
"Name":"Strawberry","Qty":5
```

I'm working in a .net 4.5 environment so I'm open to any method.

Comment: You want to look at LINQ's `GroupBy` method. If you have trouble using it, post a new question.

Comment: It's "_**pare**_ down", not "pair down".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a list of objects with a Name and Qty property?  You can use group by and aggregate:

```
var items = list _
     .GroupBy(Function(i) i.Name)  _
     .Select(Function(i) new Item With { .Name = i.Key, .Qty = i.Sum(Function(q) q.Qty) })
```

Group by groups by name, and then you can use Sum to summate the total number of items.  You can also see this from [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787802/linq-group-by-sum).

Comment: This is a VB .NET question; your answer is in the wrong language. Also, query syntax is idiomatic in VB .NET.

Comment: Edited to put back in periods and _ needed for new lines since I'm using the LINQ method approach...

Comment: You don't need the line continuation characters in vb any more if you have the period at the end of the line.

Comment: Ok I'll take your word ...  I didn't realize that...

Comment: Semi-colons at the end of a line do not make a happy VB compiler

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charm!.T

Comment: @MattWilko  haha, wow, my VB is rusty...

Answer (score 0):

You could look at creating a dictionary that stores the name as the key and then number as the value:

```
Private _dict As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    _dict = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

    AddToDictionary("Apple", 1)
    AddToDictionary("Banana", 2)
    AddToDictionary("Apple", 3)
    AddToDictionary("Banana", 4)
    AddToDictionary("Strawberry", 5)


    'The following outputs:
    'Apple : 4
    'Banana : 6
    'Strawberry : 5

    For Each kvp In _dict
        Debug.WriteLine(kvp.Key & " : " & kvp.Value)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub AddToDictionary(name As String, value As Integer)
    If _dict.ContainsKey(name) Then
        _dict(name) += value
    Else
        _dict.Add(name, value)
    End If
End Sub
```